# How to plot multiple 3d lines with an angular offset from an initial line?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I have plotted a line say `x/a + y/b + z/c = 0` and want to plot a set of 3d lines with an angular offset of say `5 deg` i.e. I want to plot many lines which make an `angle <= 5 deg` with the initial line.

```
# my plot function with takes t = [a;b;c] as argument

def plot(t):
    z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    x = z*t[0]/t[2]
    y = z*t[1]/t[2]

    ax.plot(x, y, z, label=t)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Angular offset in which direction?

Comment: Multiple lines need to be drawn in various directions at an angular offset for training the machine on this set so that it can classify any unseen data into such categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the 3d sections of this link :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)

> In three dimensions, lines can not be described by a single linear
>   equation, so they are frequently described by parametric equations.

```
x = x0 + a * t
y = y0 + b * t
z = z0 + c * t
```

where:

x, y, and z are all functions of the independent variable t which ranges over the real numbers.
(x0, y0, z0) is any point on the line.

a, b, and c are related to the slope of the line, such that the vector v = (a, b, c) is parallel to the line.

Thus to solve your problem, you have to find a1, b1, c1 such that the vectors (a,b,c) and (a1,b1,c1) have the desired angle offset. Then you draw the line.

To find v1 = (a1,b1,c1), you can use the property of the scalar product :

```
v1.v = a.a1 + b.b1 + c.c1 and v1.v = |v1|.|v|.cos(angle)
```